# Disable the iPhone when user going over 10mph

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, ios6

How can i disable the phone when user going over 10mph , disable means user can't use email or any text writing work.I am able to calculate the speed but not disable or hang the iPhone.

Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Unable to do any thing please tell me

Comment: A brilliant example of a terrible question!

Answer (score 4):

You can't, You might be able to make your own app give a warning that you are traveling to fast. But there is no way to disable to iPhone.

All apps are sandbox and have limited acces to the other apps or the system.

Comment: If there is any way to show temprary  view on iPhone,when speed is fast.By which user can't use email

Comment: In Background inside LocationUpdate...Is there any way to do  forcefully unable the user to use iphone

Comment: What part of NO do you not understand, NO you will not be able to lock the system from your app. There is no wat to achieve what you want, it can not be done.

Comment: I understand all type of No. You not need angree because you are really good guy. Thnaks rckoenes thankyou very much